# Is it possible to send part of vector as a vector to a function?

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

I want to see if it is possible to pass part of vector to a function so that it appears as a normal vector to the function. More importantly, I want this to be done in O(1), constant time. I don't want to iterate the vector to make a new one. In fact, I also want the size of the new vector to change to 40 in the following example.

```
void func(vector <int> &v){

    //calling index 10  to 50 of v
    func(v[10..50])
}
```

Comment: It's usually done with iterator ranges (see the functions from `<algorithm>`)

Comment: It is possible to send a pair of iterators.

Comment: Sending two iterators is the idiomatic way of doing it in C++.

Comment: Iterators as function parameters is not thread safe. Rather send the vector, the upper and lower limits, use mutex to protect the vector.

Comment: @ark1974 That's a bit of far fetched here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use iterators as the parameters to the range-based function, and pass in the required range. Your code in the function become

```
funcWithRange(v.cbegin()+10, v.cbegin()+50);
```

with function signature

```
void funcWithRange(std::vector<int>::const_iterator first, std::vector<int>::const_iterator last)
```

This could be generalized by making this a function template with the `vector` member type as its template parameter, or still further to any container supporting this type of range iteration.  As noted in the comments, `<algorithm>` has many examples of this pattern.

`std::distance(first, last);` will return the desired altered size.  I don't think you can get closer to meeting your requirements without making a physical copy.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if it is possible to do with only one argument

Comment: I doubt it, and wonder how that makes it more efficient anyway.  I imagine some transformation would have to occur, and you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi Yes, use a `std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator,std::vector<int>::iterator>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a vector of say 100 elements

```
std::vector<int> v(100);
```

and you want to call `void f(std::vector<int> v)` with the first 10 elements, simply call the function as

```
f({v.cbegin(), v.cbegin() + 10});
```

That will construct a new vector from the two iterators (by copying the elements) and pass the new vector to `f`.

Comment: This solution has the drawback, that the function will no longer operate on the original vector.

Comment: This is really interesting, but does this copy the vector? I don't think it works in constant time independent of the length of the range.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi Yes, this is copying to create a new vector. You can't avoid copying if you require a new vector. This is why iterators are used so much in C++. You need to rethink your requirements.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi Yes, this would create a copy of the subpart.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ true. I just wanted to present it as an option. A. Mashreghi yes, it copies.

Comment: `std::vector<int> v{100};` will call the constructor taking `std::initializer_list` and construct a vector with size 1, no?

Answer (score 3):

There is a means to achieve something similar to this that is being proposed for inclusion in the `C++` standard. It is called a `span` and it operates like a vector in some ways.

```
#include <gsl/span>

void func(gsl::span<int> sp)
{
    for(auto& i: sp)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    // ...

    std::vector<int> v(100);

    // put something in the vector (numbers 0 - 99)
    std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

    // wrap the container in a span
    auto sp = gsl::make_span(v);

    // send parts of it to functions
    func(sp.subspan(10, 50));
}
```

The `span` presents a window onto the original vector so it is a *reference type*. It doesn't contain its own data just pointers to the data in the vector. As such they are lightweight and designed to be passed by value.

An implementation of `span` can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL

This is the recommended way of passing contiguous containers in the **Best Practices** guide by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter.

The guidelines can be found here: [CppCoreGuidelines.md](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)

Comment: What's the difference from a `std::pair` of two iterators?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The `span` is bounds checked and the `API` supposed to be more robust making it hard to obtain an out-of-bounds range. Doing `v.begin() + 50` out of bounds won't trigger an exception it will quietly do undefined behavior. But `sp.subspan(0, 50)` will be checked.

Comment: @Galik If I manipulate the subspan passed to func, does that change the original values in sp? I mean is this a copy or a reference to originial?

Comment: @A.Mashreghi It is a reference, the changes happen to the original vector

Comment: @A.Mashreghi Otherwise you would have to make a copy which can't happen in `O(1)`